# Install a TCP/IP Printer Port and Printer w/ Script, User inputted IP

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I'm looking to combine a few scripts i've found on the internet on which to make a script to make it easier to install a TCP/IP Printer Port and Printer.

Firstly i'm wanting to enter 4 digits which will fit into this IP for example:

```
@echo off
set /p id=Enter ID: 1234 
echo %id%
```

The ID I input will fill in gaps with this script:

```
On Error Resume Next 

'SETS 'LOAD DRIVER' PRIVILEGE. 

    Set objWMIService = GetObject("Winmgmts:") 
    objWMIService.Security_.Privileges.AddAsString "SeLoadDriverPrivilege", True 

'SETS PRINTER PORT. 

    Set objNewPort = objWMIService.Get _ 
        ("Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort").SpawnInstance_ 
    objNewPort.Name        = "Brother" 
    objNewPort.Protocol    = 1 
    objNewPort.HostAddress = "10.12.34.90" '<<< ID WILL FILL IN THIS SECTION 
    objNewPort.PortNumber  = "9100" 
    objNewPort.SNMPEnabled = False 
    objNewPort.Put_ 

'SETS PRINTER TO PORT. 

    Set objPrinter = objWMIService.Get _ 
        ("Win32_Printer").SpawnInstance_ 
    objPrinter.DriverName = "Brother HL-1270N" 
    objPrinter.PortName   = "Brother" 
    objPrinter.DeviceID   = "Brother HL-1270N" 
    objPrinter.Location = "Front Office" 
    objPrinter.Network = True 
    objPrinter.Shared = False 
    'objPrinter.ShareName = 
    objPrinter.Put_ 

'SETS PRINTER AS DEFAULT. 

    Set colInstalledPrinters =  objWMIService.ExecQuery _ 
        ("Select * from Win32_Printer Where Name = 'Brother HL-1270N'") 
    For Each objPrinter in colInstalledPrinters 
        objPrinter.SetDefaultPrinter() 
    next
```

I'm stuck at a crossroads on what type of Conditionals to use such as IF etc.

Comment: Welcome as a new user to [SO]. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. How can a 4 digit ID fit into an IPv4 address which has 4 octets from 0..255 ? To pass a value from a batch to a vbscript transfer it via command line argument  or environment variable.

Comment: I see, would you think this section would be similar? http://users.telenet.be/mydotcom/howto/scripts/sysadmin/printers_tcpip.htm

Comment: [SO] is not a forum but a site for programmers seeking help with a distinct problem presented in a [mcve]. Your title, tags and question are ambiguous.